# Executing informatica workflow in Java

Tags: java, informatica

I am trying to run Informatica workflows from java using jlmapi. But I am unable to make the connection itself as I am getting an error. This is my code:-

```
public class executeWorkflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IJLMDriver ld = null;
        IJLMConnection connection = null;

        try {
            ld = DriverFactory.getDriver("JLMDriver10");
        } catch (JLMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            ld.initialize("C:\\ExecuteWorkflow_WIN64_v1\\lib\\lib\\locale");
        } catch (JLMException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection = ld.getConnection("domain_name",6005,180,null);
        } catch (JLMException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        try {
            connection.login("","Repository","admin","pwd",null);
        } catch (JLMException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        IJLMServerDetails srvdetails = null; 
        try {
        srvdetails =connection.getServerDetails(EJLMMonitorServerMode.ALL,null);
        } catch (JLMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("Server Status: "+srvdetails.getStatus().toString()); 
        IJLMWorkflowDetails[] workflow = srvdetails.getWorkflows(); 
        System.out.println("Number of Workflows: " + workflow.length ); 
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error Code: -109 Error Message: Unable to establish connection with Informatica Server Message Context: IJLMDriver::getConnection(domain,6005,180)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.lm.JLMException.handleExceptionOrWarning(JLMException.java:545)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.lm.JLMDriver10.getConnection(JLMDriver10.java:197)
    at informatica.executeWorkflow.main(executeWorkflow.java:93)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at informatica.executeWorkflow.main(executeWorkflow.java:99)
```

What I am doing wrong? and also what is the 180 near the port number in the getConnection parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The above code is not working because there is an API for Informatica versions starting from 10. This is 9.6.1 hence not compatible with the API. There is a workaround for this. You can use the pmcmd.batch file to run the workflows. You can call the .exe file from your java code. I had asked a question regarding that as well. You can find the code here - [Running pmcmd from java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46592292/7428604)